# What is the right way to separate redux sagas into files?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I was not able to find a reliable source of how doing it.

I'm trying to structure my app in the following form:

- Container 1

  - container.js
  - reducer.js
  - selectors.js
  - sagas.js
- Container 2

  - container.js
  - reducer.js
  - selectors.js
  - sagas.js

And to have one root saga file that would just import all the sub-sagas and let things happen.

My typical saga file looks like this:

```
/**
 * watch something
 */
function* watchSomething() {
    yield takeLatest(GET_SOMETHING, callGetSomething);
}

export const somethingSagas =  [
    watchSomething
];

export default watchSomething;
```

And my root saga:

```
import JolterSagas from '/path/to/container/sagas';

export default function* root() {
    yield all([
        SomethingSagas.map((saga) => fork(saga))
    ]);
};
```

Although working, I get the following in my console:

> [...effects] has been deprecated in favor of all([...effects]), please update your code

And no matter how I change the code, it's either not working or keeps printing this warning.

I wasn't able to find any up-to-date reliable document that shows how to do that, all the examples in the official docs are small and one-filed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are importing `takeEvery` and `takeLatest` from `redux-saga`
You have to import `takeEvery` and `takeLatest` from `redux-saga/effects`

```
import { takeEvery, takeLatest, fork } from `redux-saga/effects`
```

and

```
yield all(SomethingSagas.map((saga) => fork(saga)));
```

And there's no **right** way to structure your sagas. It dependes on your project, your coding style.

Comment: Actually no, I import it from effects

Comment: @superuser123 And did you delete [ ] in function* root?

Comment: @superuser123 Accept this answer, if this helped you! Thanks.